# Can String assignment cause memory leak?

Tags: java, memory-leaks, java-me

In my J2ME code, I have a loop which look like this,

```
 Enumeration jsonEnumerator = someJSONObject.keys();

while(jsonEnumerator.hasMoreElements()){

String key = (String) jsonEnumerator.nextElement();
String value = someJSONObject.getJSONObject(key);
someOtherJson.put(value,key);
}
```

Considering that String assignments in the above Code

```
String key = (String) jsonEnumerator.nextElement();
```

Is that the right approach to use a pool of Strings instead of instantiating new Objects or what are the other approaches to assign the strings which will avoid memory leaks?

Comment: Java doesn't "leak" (at least not until you get into JNI or Android images).  What *can* happen is that you "forget" large object structures and leave them addressable when you're no longer using them.

Answer (score 2, accepted):

The String assignments won't cause a memory leak.

Whether there the strings leak elsewhere in that code depends on a couple of things that can't be discerned from this code:

- How the JSON implementation is creating the key and value strings.  (If it is using `String.substring()` on a much larger String, you may leak storage via a shared string backing array.)
- Whether the `someOtherJson` is being leaked.

The normal approach (in Java SE) is to not worry about it ... until you've got evidence from memory profiling that there *is* a leak.  In Java ME implementations, memory is typically more constrained, and GC implementations can be relatively slow.  So it can be necessary to reduce the number and size of objects (including strings).  But that's not a memory leak issue ... and I'd still advise profiling *first* instead of leaping into a memory efficiency campaign that could be a waste of effort.

---

> Is that the right approach to use a pool of Strings instead of instantiating new Objects or what are the other approaches to assign the strings which will avoid memory leaks?

As I said there is no leak in the above code.

String pools don't eliminate leaks, and they don't necessarily reduce the rate of garbage object creation.  They *can* reduce the number of live String objects at any given time, but this comes at a cost.

If you want to try this approach, it is simplest to use `String.intern()` to manage your String pool.  But it won't necessarily help.  And can actually make things worse.  (If there isn't enough potential for sharing, the space overheads of the interned string pool can exceed the saving.  In addition, the interned string pool creates more work for the GC - more tracing, and more effectively weak references to deal with.)

Comment: But String.intern needs to be used with care.  You can easily make things worse.

Comment: And note that the main reason for using String.intern is to allow strings to be compared by address.  If you try to "pool" strings with intern you're apt to INCREASE the amount of heap used unless you have a very good understanding of what's going on.

Answer (score 1):

No, String assignment, by itself does not create anything.  The only thing resembling a "leak" in Java is when you put a whole bunch of references into some array or other structure and then forget about it -- leave the structure "live" (accessible) but don't use it.

Answer (score 0):

If you're talking about *interning strings*, then it doesn't happen here. It only happens automatically for constant strings which are found in your source code.

Any other strings will be garbage collected, just like any other object.

Comment: It's called "interning", and you *can* do it with non-constant strings, but it takes an explicit call to String.intern.

Comment: OP was asking about his particular scenario. (I see now that the question has been edited, but he was first asking about memory leaks that occur as a result of intern and string pooling).

Comment: Except that the OP didn't know what he was talking about when he said "pooling", and he never mentioned "intern".

Comment: The only way to talk about memory leaks here is by considering interning. It was implicit.

Answer (score -2):

My suggestion is:

```
Enumeration jsonEnumerator = someJSONObject.keys();

while(jsonEnumerator.hasMoreElements()) {
    String key = (String) jsonEnumerator.nextElement();
    someOtherJson.put(someJSONObject.getJSONObject(key), key);
}
```

String instantiation will cause to memory leak in J2ME because J2ME uses a poor Garbage Collection method to reduce the resource usage.

When you are trying to develop a J2ME application, be careful about memory and CPU usages.

Comment: A slow garbage collector is not a storage leak.

Comment: How does your version differ from the original?  Simply assigning a String value to a local reference does not create a new String.

Comment: J2ME Garbage Collector is not slow. It uses a poor way to collect garbages and does not work so good. And about the assignment, there is no new version of String but in your code you will create a new reference to your String and any reference is a pointer and it will stored in memory and because of poor garbage collection, it will not collected in some cases.

Comment: you can read this link: [link](http://www.javaperformancetuning.com/tips/j2me.shtml#REF6)

Comment: @SasanYavari - I read the linked page, and I don't see where it supports what you are saying.  Please elaborate.